# How to break links between created objects

Tags: ruby

I want to make a hash of arrays.

If I do this:

```
res = Hash[(1..5).zip Array.new(5, [])]
```

I will get this as result:

```
{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[], 4=>[], 5=>[]}
```

It's ok. But, when I try to change one of this array, Ruby changes them all, and that is not OK.

If I do this:

```
res[1] << 1
```

I will get this as result:

```
{1=>[1], 2=>[1], 3=>[1], 4=>[1], 5=>[1]}
```

I was trying to use other variants, like:

```
res = Hash[(1..5).zip Array.new(5, Array.new)]
res = Hash[(1..5).zip Array.new(5, [].dup)]
res = Hash[(1..5).zip Array.new(5, [].clone)]
res = Hash[(1..5).zip Array.new(5, []).clone]
```

But they gave me the same result.

Why?

Comment: `res = Hash[(1..5).zip 5.times.map { [] }]`

Comment: `res = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] if (1..5) === k }` is the best way to accomplish what you’ve wanted.

Comment: This exact problem and its solution is covered in the documentation of `Array::new` as well as several existing [so] questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First solution seems good to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a block into the `Array.new` method to get elements with different object IDs. Each array will then be a different object:

```
res = Hash[(1..5).zip(Array.new(n){[]})]
```